# node js express mongoose api save operation not working

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I am creating my first node js api using Mongoose and Express. Facing some issue when i try to post the data it does not work. Postman request never completes and data does not get saved. Please find attached code and help me figure out the issue. Also note that db connection gets established successfully.

```
//Post.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: "string",
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: "string",
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: "Date",
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Posts", PostSchema);

// Posts.js  => Routes
const express = require("express");
const Post = require("../models/post");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Posts");
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);

    const post = new Post({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
    });

    post
      .save()
      .then((data) => res.json(data))
      .catch((err) => res.json(err));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;

// app.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv/config");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//Import Routes
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");

//Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Routes
app.use("/posts", postRoute);

// Connect to db
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  () => {
    console.log("connected to db !");
  }
);

app.listen(3000);
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like something is wrong with db connection itself. Below is my connection string. I handled the mongoose connection on error and i get the error shown in screen shot.

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds023550.mlab.com:23550/roofapp
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just pasted your code here and is working fine for both post and get.

Are you able to complete the GET request?

How is your project structured?

Make sure you are importing the files correctly.

From your commented out file names you have Post.js with capital letter and you are importing posts. It seems that something is wrong in the imports.

Here is a working solution based on the code you've posted.

Files : app.js - Post.js - Router.js

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// require("dotenv/config");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//Import Routes
const postRoute = require("./Router");

//Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Routes
app.use("/posts", postRoute);

// Connect to db
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test",
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  () => {
    console.log("connected to db !");
  }
);

app.listen(3000);
```

Post.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: "string",
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: "string",
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: "Date",
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Posts", PostSchema);
```

Router.js

```
const express = require("express");
const Post = require("./Post");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Posts");
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);

    const post = new Post({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
    });

    post
      .save()
      .then((data) => res.json(data))
      .catch((err) => res.json(err));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image]

Comment: i think importing is just fine as my post method is being hit and i can see the output of console.log(req.body); but something goes wrong while saving the data which i am not really sure about.

Comment: Hmm... so the issue is actually connecting to mongodb rather than node express etc.  Are you sure the roofapp database exists? Also from the uri you posted you are not passing dbuser and db password. Make sure you change that to actual values :) .

Comment: Yes i already did that. Now i am getting different errors. Trying to resolve that. will post here shortly.